# Глючит border-radius при position:absolute

Tags: css3, html

Я указал `border-radius`. Однако он не везде сработал. В webkit-е он фурычит, а в осле 9, например, нет. Мне кажется что это из-за абсолютного позиционирования. Как исправить?

p.s. position менять нельзя.

Comment: Вы указали только `border-radius`? Или с префиксами `-moz-` и `-webkit-` тоже?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, позиционирование тут не причём (хотя с ослами и это возможно). Это связано с тем, что это свойство `CSS3` хоть и указывается, как поддерживаемое всеми браузерами, на деле не является таковым. Ну так уж повелось. Стандарт не принят - браузеры "воюют" между собой. Что-то я увлекся философскими разговорами.

Мой совет - добавьте в стили вендорные префиксы, например:

`-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-ms-border-radius: 2px;
-o-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;`

Либо примените `PIE.js` - очень полезный плагин.